# How do I fix my MySQL error 1093

Tags: mysql, sql

How to fix this error

`[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'user_log' for update in FROM clause`

```
DELETE 
  user_log
FROM
  user_log
WHERE
  UpdateDate < (SELECT MAX(UpdateDate) 
    FROM user_log 
    AS lookup 
    WHERE Email = user_log.Email)
```

Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to delete data of table then you use:

[delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) from [table] where [condition].

also for [max](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) you have to group your data first.

```
DELETE 
FROM
  user_log
WHERE
  UpdateDate < (SELECT MAX(UpdateDate) 
    FROM user_log 
    GROUP BY Email
    HAVING Email = user_log.Email)
```

when you want to use a condition on a group by then you have to use having instead of where.

Comment: Actually, you don't need GROUP BY and HAVING in this query for MySQL. When you use an aggregate function without doing a GROUP BY, the aggregate function operates on the whole result set. So just using MAX with WHERE will do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

change to ;

```
DELETE 
FROM
  user_log
WHERE
  UpdateDate < (SELECT MAX(UpdateDate) 
FROM user_log 
GROUP BY Email
HAVING Email = user_log.Email)
```

You cannot specify which fields are deleted in the `DELETE` statement, they all are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your trying to do but you may be trying to do this

```
DELETE FROM  user_log
WHERE  UpdateDate < (
    SELECT MAX(UpdateDate)     
    FROM user_log AS lookup     
    WHERE Email = lookup.Email
)
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: for max you have to use group by and where